# Positional argument error when trying to call a function with a parameter with is the counter variable of a loop

Tags: python, function, chess

I am trying to code a function to see whether one of the conditions for checks are being violated and if so not allow a castle move to be made. The self.squareUnderAttack method takes in two numbers.

```
if move.moveType == MoveType.Castling:
                #Queenside
                if move.initialCol > move.endCol:
                    if any(self.squareUnderAttack(move.initialRow,i) for i in range(move.endCol,move.initialCol+1) ): # checks whether or not the king is in check or the square in between where its moving to are being attacked 
                        moves.remove(move)

                else: # Kingside
                    if any(self.squareUnderAttack(move.initialRow,i) for i in range(move.initialCol,move.endCol+1) ): # checks whether or not the king is in check or the square in between where its moving to are being attacked 
                        moves.remove(move)
```

I do not understand why I am getting the positional argument error:
TypeError: GameState.squareUnderAttack() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
I could do it by not looping and just using or a bunch of times and calling the function separately but I would like to know why the code isn't working.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should really post the definition of `squareUnderAttack`. Provide a [mre].

Comment: Post the definition of `squareUnderAttack`.  Did you remember to include the initial `self` argument in the definition of the method?  If not, then that's your answer.  It should look like `def squareUnderAttack(self, arg1, arg2):`

Comment: You are calling self.squareUnderAttack(move.initialRow, i) inside the generator expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake, set up undersquareattack to accept a tuple as answer so I was missing a pair of brackets. Sorry for wasting everyone's time

Comment: After reading around a bit more I think the reason it counted 3 was because it was counting self as a parameter

Comment: I pointed this out in my comment.  I guess you missed it.